# Large Purple Line Displayed in Web Report Viewer

Tags: reporting-services

I recently deployed a report to our report server (SSRS) and when it renders within a browser, one of the textboxes displays a large purple line underneath the expression. This does not happen when rendered in Visual Studio. The color appears to change with each browser, in Chrome its purple, in Edge its Red.

What in the world is going on here?

[image]

Actively digging into this and I noticed that when inspecting the element the DOM Explorer it lists text-decoration: underline for that element, but when I expand it, it specifically says none.

EDIT-----

Digging further from the DOM Explorer has yielded that the Text Box next to the affected one also has "text-decoration" listed, but it specifies "none". Interestingly when I uncheck the box, that Text Box becomes underlined.

[image]

[image]

-----EDIT-----

It has something to do with the Go to Report action I have with that Expression. When I remove that, the underline goes away. Still doesn't quite  make sense though, each expression to the right and left of this one also have the exact same Go to Report action, but no line shows up on them.

Comment: Have you double checked all the expressions for that label?

Comment: @RossBush Yep, effects are set to Default, and the code view of the report does not list TextDecoration for this Expression. In fact, in everyplace that TextDecoration does appear within the code view, it is set to None. I feel like I'm going crazy here ha.

EDIT
It has something to do with the Go to Report action I have with that Expression. When I remove that, the underline goes away. Still doesn't quite  make sense though, each expression to the right and left of this one also have the exact same Go to Report action, but no line shows up on them.

Comment: @MPJ567 Yup the ACTION sometimes will assign a hyperlink line, sometimes it won't. It's really annoying. I think I recall string manipulation in expressions seemed to reset formatting and add the default HREF underline. I tried several ways to fix this and as far as I can tell it is a bug.